# Why do stars appear so close in universe photos?

Tags: astronomy, astrophotography

I saw an extremely sharp picture (from NASA/ESA) of the Andromeda Galaxy recently, and it made me wonder why the stars appear so close together, when I know in fact that they are not.

Is it simply because there are many stars behind stars, so that even if two stars are far away in terms of "depth" from our line of sight, one star may be offset from this line of sight by a little bit, which makes two stars appear "side-by-side" and thus close? Or are there multiple factors at play?

Also, if the above explanation about the line of sight is correct, why do we see distinct points as stars and distinct dark spaces between them? Shouldn't stars that are much further away still emit a faint light, thus making the background darkness of space brighter (or create gradients of light, rather than being completely black)?

Sorry if this is a bad question; I wasn't able to find very much information online.

[image: Image taken by Hubble Telescope]

Comment: Try Googling "Olber's Paradox."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct; the stars appear close together because they are far away.

Relatively nearby stars are resolvable as distinct points, but in very distant galaxies it is often not possible to resolve individual stars.

Dark spaces between individual stars are actually full of stars and galaxies full of stars.  Those spaces appear dark either just in contrast with the relatively nearby stars, or because of dust clouds between us and the stars/galaxies in those spaces.

One other factor contributes:  Light from extremely distant galaxies is red-shifted due to cosmic expansion, such that the farther away a galaxy is, the more red-shifted its light is. If the light spectrum is shifted far enough to be below the visible range, we cannot see it.  As a result, the universe can look very different when imaged using a radio telescope vs a visible light telescope.